# Approximation of non-measurable functions with non-measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

**Theorem:** If $f$ is a *measurable* function on a set $E$, then it is a limit of a uniform convergent sequence of simple *measurable* functions $\{g_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, that is

$f(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}g_n(x)$.

The proof is rather simple. We just take $E_{l,m} = \{x\in E | f(x) \in [\frac{l}{2^m}; \frac{l+1}{2^m})\} $ and $g_n(x) = \frac{l}{2^m}$. But what is special about measurability? What if I miss italic words? I know that with this theorem I may consider a measurable function as "nearly" continous, otherwise I just don't the construction of Lebesgue sets (it may be continous not "almost everywhere"). So, is the reason we don't use this theorem without measurability just because it would be useless?

Comment: Those $E_{l,m}$ are only measurable sets themselves if $f$ is measurable.

Comment: Yes, I know. But we may omit it, then $E_{l, m}$ won't be measurable. But I still can approximate $f$ with $g_n$. Why don't we do this?

Comment: I believe in theory this would be fine. The reason it's not done is because approximation of measurable functions by simple functions is usually done in the context of defining the Lebesgue integral of $f$, which is defined as the supremum of $\sum_{i = 1}^{N_n} \mu(E_{i,n})\cdot a_{i,n}$ where $\sum_{i = 1}^{N_n} a_{i,n}\chi_{E_{i,n}}$ is a simple function approximation converging to $f$ as $n \to \infty$ like in your example. Thus we need $\mu(E_{i,n})$ to be defined.